# Haskellの(>>=)におけるモナド則の適用について

Tags: haskell

https://ja.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/%E5%9C%8F%E8%AB%96
に`fmap`と`join`を使ったモナド則として`join . fmap (fmap f) = fmap f . join`というものがあります。
ここで`(>>=)`の定義は`x >>= f = join (fmap f x)`なので、
`(>>=)`を使った計算に対して`m >>= f >>= g = join . join . fmap (fmap g) . fmap f $ m`という変換ができることになると思います。つまりjoinを後からまとめて行うという変換です。
これは`(>>=)`をいくつ繋げても同じように変換可能ですが、そもそもこの形のモナド則を`f :: a -> m b`のような関数に適用していいのでしょうか？
説明での前提は`f :: a -> b`の関数のようですが。

追記
`m >>= f = join . fmap f $ m`を`m`からの射をとして考えるのではなく、`join $ fmap f m`つまり`join`を`fmap f m`からの射として考えれば、自然に可換図が作れました。

Comment: 参考までに、回答の承認（回答左側のチェックマーク）はこの回答で解決したという目印なので、もし解決に至っていないなら承認しなくても構いません。知っての上でしたらすみません。

Comment: 質問を整理してから出直したいと思うので、その時に回答をお願いしたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

端的にいうと、逆で、モナド則を満たすように、 f を実装してください、そうすれば、 (>>=) や do 記法などで問題なく使えるよ、ということです。

Comment: モナドで使うのは自己関手なので関数(射)自体はHaskellの関数である限り問題ないと思いますが。

Comment: 私が、 @fingerweek さんの問題を正確に理解できていない可能性がある気がしています。あと、私は圏論自体はそこまで詳しくないので、自己関手が何なのかわかっていないです。

Comment: こちらの質問し方も悪かったようです。

Comment: ああ、なんとなくわかった気がしていて、圏論における自己関手を関数でもって代替している、みたいなことに、 Haskell の >>= まわりはなっているけれども、それってそもそも大丈夫なんでしたっけ？みたいなことですかね。。？

Comment: 質問はつまり、あまり上手く言えませんが、射の型に依存した形の式でもモナド則は有効かということですが、もっと考えをまとめようと思います。